# What is the name of the topic for studying subsets of higher dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I forget where I read this, probably it was in a differential geometry book or a physics book. There is some obscure name for the study of higher dimensional spaces by looking at only slices of fewer dimensions of that space. An example would be a graph or chart showing only two dimensions of an n=4 Riemannian manifold. Basically I'm looking for a mathematics book on the topic of representing slices of the higher dimensional spaces and I can't remember the specific name of that discipline.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of foliations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation

Comment: Do you refer to the generation of quasi-periodic tilings (like Penrose tilings) by a "strip projection method" like : "A Geometrical Approach of Quasiperiodic Tilings" by Christophe Oguey, Michel Duneau, and Andre Katz available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38330313_A_geometrical_approach_of_quasiperiodic_tilings) ?

Comment: Was it Morse Theory by any chance? It aims to analyze manifolds by slicing them by level sets of Morse functions. However, in this case, for 4-dimensional manifolds you'd be looking at 3-dimensional slices. in order to get to 2d-slices one considers (less known but very useful) "theory of Morse-2 functions."

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, you jogged my memory. Foliation was the answer (from @QiaochuYuan), but I realize that Morse Theory (from @MoisheKohan) is closely related and I probably need a book on that too. I've also downloaded the PDF mentioned by @JeanMarie. All are part of what I am trying to study.

The lesson is that I didn't even know to ask the right question. :)